# How to specify axis range without modifying dataset scale?

Tags: image-charts

I would like to know how to set the axis range and achieve the same behavior that Google Image Charts had. Here is the example for the same request URL:

[image: Google Image Charts]

[image: Image Charts]

I.e., I have an y value on each 100th of x axis. Is there a way to easily define a dataset 'step' for Image Charts, or I have to create custom labels on x axis with `chxl`, which I would like to avoid?

Answer (score 1):

Image-Charts founder here :)

Indeed, regarding axis range our documentation is (I hope) explicit:

> In Google Image Charts specifying the chxr parameter changed the scale of the axis but not the dataset scale. In Image-Charts — because we think it's was the biggest usage issue with Google Image Charts — changing the axis scale through chxr also impact the whole dataset scale.

> You must make an axis visible using the chxt parameter if you want to specify its range.

You will have to use axis range (`chxr`) to better specify what you want and the steps needed:

```
chxr=
  <axis_index>,<start_val>,<end_val>,<opt_step>
    |...|
  <axis_index>,<start_val>,<end_val>,<opt_step>
```